# how to run multiple configurations in Intellij in sequence

Tags: intellij-idea

My application has configurations/SBT Tasks for 
- building UI
- building server
- running UI tests
- running server-side tests
- create a distribution version of the application.

I want to create a configuration which runs these all in order but stop if any of the previous configuration fails.

I created a configuration which uses other configurations but it doesn't move to the next configuration after the 1st one.

[image]

I also tried to create a Compound configuration but it is not possible to specify order/sequence as it runs all configurations in parallel.

Is there a way to run multiple configurations in sequence depending on the outcome of previous configuration?

Comment: Does the first task in Before Launch finish with the zero exit code?

Comment: It should. I am running this task `ui-test := {
    implicit val UIroot = baseDirectory.value / "ui"
    if (runUiTests != 0) throw new Exception("UI tests failed!") else {Success}
}`. Success is `val Success = 0 // 0 exit code` in build.sbt

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: found the issue. your comment was helpful. The unit tests were running in watch mode because of which unit test were not exiting. After using watch=false for my angular ui tests, next configuration is not getting executed

Comment: I didnt understand the solution. Seems like You found your answer but how do We run services in a custom order??